Constructing the splitting field of reducible polynomials over finite fields
*I am trying to tackle the following problem without resorting to Galois theory using explicit construction.
Constructing the splitting field of reducible polynomials over finite fields (*)
Now, to construct the splitting field of an irreducible polynomial $f$, one can simply construct $L:= F[x]/\langle f\rangle$. And this is definitely an extension field that $f$ splits completely (the roots are linear combinations of $1, \bar{x}, ...,\bar{x}^{n-1}$. Moreover, $F[x]/\langle f\rangle$ is generated by $1, \bar{x}, ...,\bar{x}^{n-1}$, so it satisfies the definition of splitting field.
However, in the case of reducible $f$, $F[x]/\langle f\rangle$ is not a field. So the only hope is to decompose it into irreducible $f_1, f_2, ...$ and successively apply the above construction. However, can we make sure that $f_2$ is irreducible over $L[x]$, where $L:= F[x]/\langle f_1 \rangle$? Is this construction in general a good way to solve (*)?

You could have $f_2 = f_1$, for instance, so you cannot blindly form $L[x]/\langle f_2\rangle$ without factoring $f_2$ over $L$ first. A better approach might be to calculate $F[x] / \langle f_1\rangle, \ldots, F[x] / \langle f_k \rangle$ separately and then form the composite.

@BenSteffan thanks! could you elaborate a little on "forming the composite"?

Let $K$ be a field with algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ and let $\overline{K} / E_1, E_2 / K$ two algebraic field extensions. There is then an extension $E_1 . E_2  / K$ called the composite of $E_1$ and $E_2$ defined to be the smallest extension of $K$ containing both $E_1$ and $E_2$. In case that $E_1 = K(a_1, \ldots, a_k)$ and $E_2 = K(b_1, \ldots, b_l)$, it has the form $E_1 . E_2 = K(a_1, \ldots, a_k, b_1, \ldots, b_l)$. All of this only really makes sense after you pick an algebraic closure of  $K$; otherwise you'll have to look at a tensor product.

Moreover since this is about finite fields, all of this can reduce down to just looking at degrees.

When you "successively apply the construction", in each step you should factor the remaining $f_k, ..., f_n$ first.
